# Java: How to sort a list using foreach?

Tags: java

I've been trying to sort a filtered list once I use foreach in Java, but I can't. Could someone help me? Please. This is the code I have and I should sort:

```
List<Photo> photos = getAllPhoto();
String parteTitulo = "ipsam do";
for (Photo aux: photos){
    if(aux.getTitle().contains(parteTitulo)){
        System.out.println(aux.getTitle());
    }
}
```

This is what I get once I print it:

```
placeat ipsam doloremque possimus sint autem laborum ea expedita
sed ut aut ipsam dolore
beatae ipsam dolores consequatur eum quia inventore sit
eos sapiente ipsam dolores accusamus est et nihil odio
consequatur iure est ullam ipsam dolorem nesciunt
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: It is not practical to sort a list using "for each" because it doesn't allow you to modify the list you are iterating.  You need to loop over the list element subscripts.  (And not just a single loop.)  Look up a sort algorithm in Wikipedia.  Or better still, use Collections.sort.

Comment: I tried to use Collections.sort, but I couldn't, could you give an idea of how to use it?

Comment: Like this `Collections.sort(photos, yourComparator)`.  Seriously, look at a tutorial; e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/algorithms/index.html

Comment: Thanks, Stephen, I'm just a newbie. I just started programming six weeks ago. I've been reading a lot, but I get confused sometimes.

Comment: Fair enough.  It is difficult (to say the least) for a newbie to know that their idea for doing something won't work.  For example, sorting with a "for each" loop.  But I would recommend googling for (say) "oracle tutorial sort" before asking a question like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not sort a list while just iterating it. Because you can't decide whether it's the right position of an item to print out without knowing what is ahead in the list. So

You have to do it in 2 steps -

1. First filter the list
2. Sort the filtered list using a comparator

   ```
   List<Photo> photos = getAllPhoto();
   String parteTitulo = "ipsam do";

   List<Photo> filteredPhotos = new ArrayList<>();

   for (Photo aux : photos) {
       if (aux.getTitle().contains(parteTitulo)) {
           filteredPhotos.add(aux);
       }
   }

   filteredPhotos.sort((p1, p2) -> p1.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getTitle()));

   for (Photo aux : filteredPhotos) {
       System.out.println(aux.getTitle());
   }
   ```

Comment: Shakhawat, that was AWESOME. Thank you so much for your help.